# Whitespace between string from a variable and a comma

Tags: python

```
name = "johnny woods"

print(name.rstrip(), ",".lstrip(), "How are you feeling today?")
```

When I run it it prints

```
johnny woods , How are you feeling today?
```

There is some whitespace between 'johnny woods' and the comma. Why is this the case? And how can I avoid it?

Comment: there is also whitespace after comman and before the remaining string.. it is because print separates the arguments it prints with space

Comment: What were you hoping with: `",".lstrip()` since this is the same as `","` (i.e. since  ',' does not contain whitespace)?  Also `name.rstrip()` does not do anything either in this case.

Answer (score 3):

In general you don’t want to use `print` arguments to paste strings together. It’s much easier and more powerful to use [Python’s f-strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/):

```
print(f'{name}, how are you feeling today?')
```

Answer (score 2):

there is also whitespace after comman and before the remaining string.. it is because print separates the arguments it prints with space

to override that default value you can use `sep` named argument like this

```
print(name.rstrip(), ",".lstrip(), "How are you feeling today?", sep="")
```

but then the space after comma will go away

you can solve that using [Whitespace between string from a variable and a comma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62007068/whitespace-between-string-from-a-variable-and-a-comma/62007125?noredirect=1#comment109668857_62007125)

Comment: You can do `print(name.rstrip(), ",".lstrip(), " How are you feeling today?", sep="")` to get the space after comma

Comment: i know ... but not sure of the requirement of OP

Comment: i will update answer to point to your comment as well , thanks

Comment: No need for the `*strip` methods.

Comment: @skrrrt Sure, but using `strip` here isn’t an alternative solution, it’s plain unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

The [`print`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) function has a `sep` argument which defaults to `' '`. The `sep` is used to seperate the objects passed to it. To remove the whitespace, you can do,

```
print(name, ",", "How are you feeling today?", sep='')
```

Answer (score 0):

- Try this

```
name = "johnny woods"

print(name.strip() + ", How are you feeling today?")
```

- output:

```
johnny woods, How are you feeling today?
```

Comment: In this code he perform only concatenate operation, So we no need of extra `lstrip` methods